# Find $P(B_3>0,B_6>0)$ where $(B_t)$ is a Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, brownian-motion

Suppose that $B_{t}$ is a standard Brownian Motion. What is the probability that both $B_{3}$ and $B_{6}$ take positive values?

This is what I've tried but then I get stuck and I'm not sure how to proceed next:

\begin{align*}
P(B_{3} > 0, B_{6})&= P(B_{3} - B_{2} > B_{2}, B_{6}-B_{5} > -B_{5})\\
&=\int_{-b_{5}}^{\infty}\int_{-b_{2}}^{\infty} \phi(b_{3})\phi(b_{6}) db_{3}db_{6}\\
&=\int_{-b_{5}}^{\infty} [\Phi(b_{3})]_{-b_{2}}^{\infty}  \phi(b_{6}) db_{6}\\
&=\int_{-b_{5}}^{\infty} \Phi(b_{2})\phi(b_{6}) db_{6}\\
\end{align*}

This is where I get stuck. I'm not sure how to integrate it at this point. Is there an alternative approach to this problem?

Comment: Note that $(B_3,B_6)=(X,X-Y)$ where $(X,Y)$ is i.i.d. centered normal hence, considering the common PDF $\varphi$ and CDF $\Phi$ of $X$ and $Y$, one gets $$P(B_3>0,B_6>0)=P(X>0,X>Y)=E(\Phi(X);X>0)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\Phi(x)\varphi(x)dx=\left.\tfrac12\Phi(x)^2\right|_{0}^{\infty}=\tfrac38.$$

Comment: @Did Or one can simply make a drawing after your initial identification.

Comment: @Henrik And use the invariance of the distribution of (X,Y) by the rotations.

Comment: @Did exactly! :)